# Windows 8: Share a folder at network to a microsoft account user

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, home-networking

I have 3 computer at home, I want to share some files from one computer to another, but I want to share just to my user (microsoft account)...

All computer has Windows 8, and is logged in with the same microsoft account... But this computer can be logged with other account, but in this case, i dont want to share the content...

How can i do this?

Comment: I need to know how can I use the Microsoft Account to login...

Comment: There are hundreds of examples of how to convert your local account to a Microsoft Account on this very website.  There are even more on other websites.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not asking how to connect my local account with the microsoft account... I'm asking how to use a created Microsoft Account to connect to a shared folder at another computer...

Comment: You should be able to do that by joining the same Homegroup.